# Error when trying to commit changes on ubuntu netbeans 7.3 and subversion

Tags: svn, ubuntu, netbeans, ubuntu-12.04

when I moved my files to a new machine and when Im trying to commit changes I get the following window with no options to choose:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: See here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679099/netbeans-subversion-authentication-failed